# Get id of article with certain class every time document changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several articles on my page, only one article will have `class="playing"` at a time. This changes depending on user interaction. So I need to somehow check when user clicks or does something like that I need to find article with class="playing" and get it's id in a global variable.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    nowPlaying = $('article').hasClass('playing');
    nowPlaying = nowPlaying.atrr('id');
});
```

every time I click I get this error in console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'nowPlaying.atrr('id')')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atrr` is not the name of the function; use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead.

Additionally, your can shorten your code like this:

```
nowPlaying = $('article.playing').attr('id');
```

Comment: Before StackOverflow allows me to accept this answer, could you help me out with one more thing, How can I than Find article with id = nowPlaying and if there is such article do stuff, if there isn't don't do anything?

Comment: `if ($('article#nowPlaying').length) { /* do stuff */ }`